# How to Use Log4j with WebLogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Im using weblogic 10.3.6, im newbiee to weblogic server, i have created a domain.. and deployed a web application. i want to generate logs for my application, i searched in the internetm i tried using log4j.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="false">
    <appender name="log4jexample" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/${weblogic.Name}.wwwwww.log" /> 
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <root>
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="log4jexample" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

i copied log4j.xml in src folder directly, and tried copying in WEB-INF folder.. but nothing worked..`enter code here`

could any tell me how to generate log file in a specific location in 
for ex: domains/TestDomain/servers/log/specificname.log  ......

Answer (score 0):

Have you logged into the admin console, gone to your Server and set:

```
 Server link -> Logging tab -> Logging Implementation dropdown
```

It's under the advanced section. You can also specify the logging location (Log file name).  Weblogic can use log4j by default, no need to add your own log4j.xml unless you're trying to do something special that it can't do by default if you want it as the server level.

Answer (score 0):

Locate your startWebLogic.cmd file (i.e. if you using the base domain \user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd).

Add the following: (just before the `set JAVA_OPTIONS=%SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS%`)

```
set LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE=log4j.xml
set SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dlog4j.configuration=%LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE%
```

then just below that :

```
@REM set SAVE_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%
set SAVE_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;**PATHTOYOURLOG4J.XML**
set CLASSPATH=%SAVE_CLASSPATH%
set SAVE_CLASSPATH=
```

Save it then launch using the .cmd file....